# Chrome Ext Open Tab and Send Message to Content Script of Newly Created Tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open a new tab in my chrome extension from the popup (which is working) and then also pass a message to the content script that will be injected into the newly opened tab. This code is being called in my popup.js after a button is clicked within the popup.

The tab is opening as expected, but the content script is not executing as expected. I am trying to tap into the callback function of the create method. The code inside the of the callback has been tested separately and works as expected when standing alone, I just cannot figure out how to bring these to things together properly. I thought maybe this was happening b/c the content script wasn't loaded yet, so I tried somethings to wait until the tab loaded with no luck. Below is the code I have been working on.

```
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://myurl.com", index: 0}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"value": "amazon_paste", "object": chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().jsonOrderObj});
  });
});
```

Here is working code after commenting out the create tab and manually going to the url:

```
//chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://myurl.com", index: 0}, function(tab) {

        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"value": "amazon_paste", "object": chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().jsonOrderObj});
        });
//});
```

Also here is my JSON manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Amazon Order Extension",
  "version": "2.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/orders-v2/confirm-shipment/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "amazon_content_script.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["http://myurl.com"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "inventory_content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["background", "tabs"],
  "background": {
     "page": "background.html"
  },
  "description": "",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the content script is actually working via an `alert()` or a `console.log`? And could you post your _manifest.json_?

Comment: Seems my situation is the same.
At http://stackoverflow.com/q/17564324/1566008
I see callback from create behaves different then expected:(

Comment: Yes I have confirmed the content script is working via an alert. I commented out the open tab, manually went to the url in a new tab and ran the code and it worked as expected. @JeremiahMegel I added the working code example above.

Comment: @JeremiahMegel sorry I forgot to post my manifest earlier. It is posted now.

Comment: @boldSOCKS I'm having same issue. Any luck with this? Seems that creating a tab and sending a message to its content script is not a supported messaging pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For "external" sites, it looks like you should have an `"externally_connectable"` key in your `manifest.json`:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": [
    "*://*.example.com/*"
  ]
}
```

Does adding this in work for you?

Source: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage